How to serialize an object to XML specifying the date format
I have this entity:
public partial class MyRegistry
    {
        public DateTime MyDateTime { get; set; }
    }

And I am using this code to serialize:
var myRegistry = new MyRegistry()
{
    MyDateTime = DateTime.Now
};

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyRegistry));

// Deserialize from XML
using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter()) // xmlString is your XML content as string
{
    serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, myRegistry);
    // Output the XML string
    Console.WriteLine(stringWriter.ToString());
}

I got this as a result:
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyRegistry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <MyDateTime>2024-04-07T12:05:21.9739342+02:00</MyDateTime>
</MyRegistry>

I like to know how could I modify the code to write the date in a different format like: "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"
I have googled and I have seen this suggested:
public partial class MyRegistry
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime MyDateTime { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("MyDateTime")]
    public string MyDateTimeFormatted
    {
        get { return MyDateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); }
        set { MyDateTime = DateTime.Parse(value); }
    }
}

But the problem is that MyRegistry in my case is an automatically  generated class from third party xsd files. So if I edit it now to add the [XmlIgnore] the next time it is re-generated cause the xsd is updated (the real xsd has a ton of extra classes beyond the MyRegistry), my changes will be gone and we will need to remember to re-add them.
So there is anyway I can achieve what I need without editing the original xml/xsd? For example, there is no way to configure/extend the XmlSerializer so that when it serializes dates it use a specific format?

Why do you need the DateTime in a string?  The answer is to understand why you need the string and do the conversion in the code that reads/writes the string.  Not in the serialize code.

The app is supposed to generated an XML in a certain format. The third party has provided with xsd defining the structure of the object we got to create. And then a specification of how the date is supposed to look like when serialized. Since the original xsd are quite massive (you see here the hyper-simplified-date-field only version) I am looking for a solution that fills the customer requierements and does not force me to edit the xsd/xsml provided/generated to avoid a maintenance mess

The XSD defines the format of the Date Strings.  You have a conflict if the APP requires a schema and then requires the format of the Date to be different from the schema.  You may have a Front End and a Back End in you app that uses different formats.  You then need an interface that converts one format to another.  Do not try to mix the front end and back end into one class.

@jdweng is absolutely right. XML is not about presentation. XSD is enforcing proper data types. Any date in XML shall be conformant with the ISO 8601 standard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

XmlSerializer does not allow you to control the formatting of DateTime values.  You will need to introduce a surrogate string property and do it yourself.  See Can you specify format for XmlSerialization of a datetime?'.  That question is from 2009 but nothing has changed since then.
